# How are they able to style the video so fluidly?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I'm not really sure where to go from here but I saw this website - http://www.equus-automotive.com/en_US/. And it seems that the video is pretty fluid with the browser width and height. The scroll bar doesn't even show, which is what I'm trying to achieve. The video also seems to stay consistently centered.

How did they do this?

Here is what I have so far - https://jsfiddle.net/9Ly5tzws/

Thank you very much for your time and effort. I really appreciate it!

```html
<!--====================
---- Navigation Bar ----
=====================-->
<div id="navbar">

  <ul>
    <li>HOME</li>
    <li>PRODUCTS</li>
    <li>VIDEOS</li>
    <li>MUTE</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<!--==================
---- Content Wrap ----
===================-->
<div id="bgcontainer">
  <video id="bg" src="http://www.videvo.net/home.webm" autoplay="true" loop="true" muted="true"></video>
</div>


<!--============
---- Footer ----
=============-->
<div id="footer">
</div>
```

Comment: In a word.... **Javascript**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this plugins before http://vodkabears.github.io/vide/  or  https://github.com/linnett/backgroundVideo ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems like a really good solution. But unfortunately i ca'nt get it to work. Not really sure why. Thanks for your time and effort though. I set the viewport width instead and it worked just fine.

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work! Thank you so much for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

for making this work you need to know the aspect ration of your video, which is reflected in the padding-top of the container.
see http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video for a more verbose explanation. The tick is that browsers calculate padding set as a percentage based on the *width* of the containing block

```
   #bgcontainer {
        overflow: hidden;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        height: 0;
        padding-top: 56.294%;
        }

    #bg {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'll look into it.